# Why I am getting this error "ImportError: No module named pyplot" while using matplotlib in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I downloaded matplotlib wheel file and installed it using pip and it got successfully installed. But the matplotlib does not contain pyplot. What should I do?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

t = np.arange(0.0, 2.0, 0.01)
s = 1 + np.sin(2*np.pi*t)
plt.plot(t, s)

plt.xlabel('time (s)')
plt.ylabel('voltage (mV)')
plt.title('About as simple as it gets, folks')
plt.grid(True)
plt.savefig("test.png")
plt.show()
```

> Error:
>   import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>   ImportError: No module named pyplot

Comment: Do you, by any chance have a file called `matplotlib` in the same folder as your script?

Comment: @FlyingTeller Sounds like a classic mistake is brewing...

Comment: @FlyingTeller: Nope, I don't have matplotlib file in the Script folder.

Comment: Please add `import matplotlib` followed by `print(matplotlib.__file__)` to the top of your script and report the output